# In flowering plants food is transported in which form?

Tags: biochemistry, food, photosynthesis, nutrition

In flowering plants food is transported in which form? I searched on google and found that it is sucrose. Why not glucose/fructose/starch?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: why  r u asking that ?

Comment: Because homework questions are off-topic here unless you show your effort for answer. Do some research on the topic, and if you are still confused, show us the line/paragraph/article (that you read during research) which is confusing you.

Comment: i hav dun my research nd still not got my answer .... :(

Comment: nd y r homework questions not allowed......afterall they r also a part of biology ??

Comment: See Biology.SE [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) till I post an answer.

Comment: You should add all the relevant details that you would have got while doing your research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a homework question but I will answer it (forgive me moderators ;).

You will get your answer from this [answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/24668/why-should-plants-transform-glucose-into-sucrose-before-transporting-it-to-other):

> Sucrose and starch are more efficient in energy storage when compared to glucose and fructose, but starch is insoluble in water. So it can't be transported via phloem and the next choice is sucrose, being water soluble and energy efficient sucrose is chosen to be the carrier of energy from leaves to different part of the tree. Another problem exists, glucose is highly reactive and this may result in some intermediate reactions while transporting glucose. Being a complex structure, sucrose is not as much reactive as glucose. So plants uses the sucrose as a medium to transfer energy. Inside the cells, sucrose is converted back to glucose and fructose.

Once again:

1. *Glucose*- too reactive: **CANCEL**
2. *Fructose*- too reactive, again: **CANCEL**
3. *Starch*- insoluble in water: **CANCEL**
4. *Sucrose*- no problem: **ACCEPT**